# Windows Precision Touchpad not working on Asus laptop

Tags: windows-10, drivers, touchpad, asus-laptop

I've heard [good things](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/7cpf8k/get_rid_of_the_terrible_asus_smart_gesture_and/) about using the [Windows Precision TP driver](https://drivers.softpedia.com/get/Other-DRIVERS-TOOLS/Others/ELAN-Input-Device-for-WDF-Driver-161132-for-Windows-10-64-bit.shtml) as a replacement for the bug-ridden Asus SmartGesture TP. I've followed all directions (in the second link) and installed the driver without error, however it just... doesn't work. Every indication in Device Manager, Touchpad Settings, Task Manager, etc. shows Elan functioning as expected. However, none of the touch gestures work. Any ideas why?

Running Windows Home v10.0.17763 on Asus Q302LA.

Comment: The precision drivers require hardware support have you confirmed you have a compatible Touchpad?

Comment: I haven't seen any indication that it's NOT supported... Asus uses Elan drivers, the drivers installed without error and throw no errors while running (one would assume incompatible hardware would produce some kind of error indication). The drivers are WHQL-tested, and when I installed via Device Mgr, I left the box "Show compatible hardware" checked.